# How to handle race condition with cassandra updates?

Tags: cassandra, race-condition, cassandra-2.0

I am learning Cassandra. I am modeling the cassandra table for a specific use case. The use case described below -

A user can write a post. 
Other users can reply to the post.
Users can also "up vote" or "down vote" a post.
User sort the posts by date or up votes or down votes.

This is my table definition -

```
CREATE TABLE post.comments_by_post (
postid text,
parentpostid text,
createdon bigint,
username text,
userid text,
displayname text,
upvotes int,
downvotes int,
comment text,
PRIMARY KEY ((postid, parentpostid), createdon)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdon DESC);
```

To increment "upvote" I have a update query -

```
UPDATE post.comments_by_post SET upvotes = incrementedValue where postid=1 and parentpostid = 2 ;
```

**incrementedValue** is calculated adding 1 in previous value.

**incrementedValue = previousValue + 1**

My question is, if i have to calculate the increment based on the previous value, which is in the table, it will cause race condition and data corruption.

Do we have better way?

I know that cassandra has counter column definition type, which can be used for such incremental values, but it requires additional table. Counter column cannot be used with normal columns which are not part of primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following table and secondary index will allow you to implement counting without the Counter table and without any locks:

```
CREATE TABLE votes_by_comment (
   postid text,
   parentpostid text,
   userid text,
   vote text, //can be 'up' or 'down'
PRIMARY KEY (( postid, parentpostid ), userid))

CREATE INDEX ON votes_by_comment (vote);
```

When a user does 'up votes':

```
INSERT INTO votes_by_comment (postid, parentpostid, userid, vote) VALUES ('comment1', 'post1', 'user1', 'up');
```

When a user does 'down votes':

```
INSERT INTO votes_by_comment (postid, parentpostid, userid, vote) VALUES ('comment1', 'post1', 'user1', 'down');
```

`userid` as clustering column will allow it to avoid race condition and restrict multiple voting by one user.

To count up votes:

```
SELECT count(*) from votes_by_comment WHERE postid='comment1' AND parentpostid='post1' and vote='up';
```

The secondary index will allow it to perform select by `vote` value, since the select by the secondary index will be performed within a partition key, it will have good performance.

But this approach doesn't allow you to implement ordering by votes on Cassandra side, and it should be implemented on the application side.

Comment: Inserting a record will solve all the problems with race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**You will lost some update when concurrent update happened.**
Ex. User A read the current value let say 10. At the same time Another User B also read the current value he will get 10. Then user A make update request with new value 11. And then User B will also make update request with new value 11.So you have lost the User A update.

**Counter table is the best choice for you.**

> A counter is a special column used to store a number that is changed in increments.  Cassandra counters were redesigned in Cassandra 2.1 to alleviate some of the difficulties. Read [What’s New in Cassandra 2.1: Better Implementation of Counters](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters) to discover the improvements made in the counters.

You can create a counter table like this one :

```
CREATE TABLE vote_counter (
   postid text,
   parentpostid text,
   upvotes counter,
   downvotes counter,
   PRIMARY KEY((postid,parentpostid))
)
```

Now You can query like this one :

```
UPDATE vote_counter SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE postid = ? AND parentpostid = ?
UPDATE vote_counter SET upvotes = upvotes - 1 WHERE postid = ? AND parentpostid = ?
UPDATE vote_counter SET downvotes = downvotes + 1 WHERE postid = ? AND parentpostid = ?
UPDATE vote_counter SET downvotes = downvotes - 1 WHERE postid = ? AND parentpostid = ?
```

Comment: Thanks Ashraful. Creating another table will break the rule for data modelling. Like single query to read data.

Answer (score 1):

From your description:

> ...User sort the posts **by date or up votes or down votes**.

you are targeting **three use cases**, but **your table definition solves only the first one** (by date). In order to solve the other two, you need to create two tables, using the `upvotes` and `downvotes` fields as your clustering key (respectively), and take the effort to keep all three tables in sync:

```
CREATE TABLE post.comments_by_post (
    postid text,
    parentpostid text,
    createdon bigint,
    username text,
    userid text,
    displayname text,
    upvotes int,
    downvotes int,
    comment text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((postid, parentpostid), upvotes) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdon DESC);
```

If you upgrade C* and go with the 3.0, you can save a good amount of work and create a [Materialized View](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views).

Back to your concurrency problem, *counting* in distributed environment is really hard. Depending on your requirements, I suggest you **two possible solutions**:

1) **You don't need to be precise** (you can tolerate over/under counts). In this case I'd suggest you to go with a new Cassandra counter table to store your counters. The main drawback of this approach is that you actually lose the ability to get (from you application point of view) your results *in order*, so you need to apply ordering at application lever. You also save the other two tables described above, because counters stay in another table.

2) **You need to be precise**. In this case, you need to **serialize** the access to each single post counter. You can achieve this by keeping a small cache of *post counters that you're going to update, or that have been updated recently*, and acquire a *lock* on each item at application level every time you want update it. 64k posts should be enough. Now you know that for each post you perform the updates *sequentially*. You can't go wrong with this, because you don't apply a *global* lock, you only apply *local* locks. You still need three tables with C* 2.0, or one + Materialized View with C* 3.0.

Comment: This answer adds too much overhead just for changing the clustering column:
`In order to solve the other two, you need to create two tables, using the upvotes and downvotes fields as your clustering key (respectively), and take the effort to keep all three tables in sync:`

Comment: And you didn't explain why making the column sorting key helps solve the race condition.